# Jira: Display Story Points in pending Sprints also

Tags: jira, agile, scrum

In JIRA v7.0.10

When Im on the backlog screen, I can see the estimated story points of the **started sprint**, even if I toggle them. (Green Circles)
But we have some **planned sprints** also, where the story points are not visible when the given sprint is toggled. (Red Circles)

How can  Jira be configured to **show the story points** on not started sprints also?

[image]

*This is still not solved properly*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't currently display that information which represents the progress of your sprint regarding to story points

But for your sprints, which are in the status of planning, you can expand the sprint panel

[image: expand sprint panel]

then click the three points icon to view the summary of work planned, and the story points

[image: view story points here]

Comment: Thats a problem. :( Why we can see them differently? Would be nice to be able to configure the display of them. Btw, if I toggle them, and click to the tree point, I still dont see the result above, only when they are in "full view" :/

Comment: You can't see because they developed that way apparently. Indicators are displayed to show you progress on your iteration, not to plan your sprints. It would be a nonsense since the first indicator shows "todo", "in progress" and "done". Which is not our point when a team is planning a sprint

Answer (score 0):

one solution came to my mind, is you can enable parallel sprint feature which enables starting more than one sprint at a time.with this feature you will able to see the story points in all sprints. to enable parallel sprints you can login as admin and go to JIRA Agile Labs and enable the feature. you can find more information with this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-administrator-s-guide/jira-agile-labs)

UPDATE

And also story points will be displays when sprint is started.as you can see your screenshot only open sprints shows the Story points values.try to start other sprints and see.

Comment: We are already using this, but only the two open sprints have the story points when its toggled. As you can see on the a picture as well.

Comment: On update:
That is my problem. I want two sprint only per week. That is working. But the rest are planned, and we adding stoires into those sprints during the week. And we would like to see how many points are there for the next sprints. (without untoggle any of them)